# php Parsing A String With Multiple Delimiters

Tags: php, string

I want to parse string in php with multiple delimiters
I use this code

```
$pattern = '/[, ]/';

$array = preg_split( $pattern, $string);
```

This work fine , but I want to use and "[" and "]" as delimiters!!

How can I include this delimiters in $pattern. I try with `$pattern = '/[, []]/';` and `$pattern = '/[, ]/';` but error occurred.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>Escaping the brackets should work.</strike>

```
\[
```

Related: [`preg_quote()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php)

**Edit**: use [`json_decode()`](http://php.net/json_decode) instead.

Comment: I want to parse this:[41103697,20807640, 41099181,20804771, 41099064,20804712], delimiters are "[],space". When I put `\[`
$array[0] is empty string ,. and $array[3] is empty... Why? Thanks

Comment: @Jovan what kind of data is that? The example you show could be parsed using `json_decode()`